# Comment Everywhere at 49 Reputation bug?

Tags: bug, reputation

So I think this may be a bug:

[image: Comment everywhere at 49 reputation?]

I appear to have achieved the `comment everywhere` privilege with 49 reputation.

Not a huge problem, but a curiosity... Do I report this or something?

Comment: The stormtroopers have been dispatched. Face away from windows.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You probably down-voted answers right after you reached 50 points, or you got some of your posts down-voted. Once the system notifies you about a new privilege, there isn't any way to remove the notification if you lose reputation. Probably, they could add a delay on notifications for new privileges, but then there would be users complaining they aren't notified when they get new privileges.

Comment: I assume you mean to say "You probably had an answer down-voted"? Should I edit?

Comment: I was assuming you reached exactly 50 points. I expanded the answer.

Comment: I can't exactly confirm this answer as true, since I never saw the 50 reputation, but it seems reasonable and a fairly likely explanation.